# using socat to multicast an mpeg-2 stream

Tags: unix, udp, socat

I have a broken ts file containing some MPEG-2 stream, with occasional intentional packet errors. The idea is to analyze the stream on another application I am trying to build and detect the errors.

If I use *socat* as

```
socat -u open:test.ts udp:localhost:1234
sleep 0.001
```

It correctly sends the contents of the file on that socket and I can listen to that port in my client application to analyze transport stream packets. Now, I want my application to support multicast as well.For that, I use something like

```
socat -u open:test.ts udp:239.48.208.1:1234
sleep 0.001
```

and listen to that multicast address on my application. I receive nothing. Since I know that multicast address is valid within my firewall, I am assuming this is an issue of *socat* not sending any packets in the first place. So, I believe this is not the correct way to send file contents over network using *socat*.

It does not have to be an MPEG-2 stream though. I just want to know how to multicast contents of a binary file on a specific multicast address and port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried this, but there are many detailed examples on [dest-unreach.org](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-multicast.html) by Gerhard Rieger, the author of socat. The first example is of a multicast client and several receiving servers on a common network 192.168.10.*. The client 192.168.10.1 sends to a multicast address, and the receiving
servers may send response packets. On any of the servers, e.g. 192.168.10.2, we have

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:6666,ip-add-membership=224.1.0.1:192.168.10.2,fork EXEC:hostname
```

which means receive multicasts to 224.1.0.1, and fork a process for each packet. The process (eg `hostname`) can send one or more reply packets back. 192.168.10.2 is the interface to receive on (so differs on each server); see the socat man page for `ip-add-membership`.

On the sending client we have

```
socat STDIO UDP4-DATAGRAM:224.1.0.1:6666,range=192.168.10.0/24
```

which sends data from stdin to be multicast. It will print any received replies.